# Llenar <select><option> con titulos almacenados en una base de datos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

Tengo un `<select>` y quiero que este muestre titulos que estan almacenados en una base de datos. He encontrado varias fomas pero ninguna me ha sido util.
Si alguien me puede orientar se los agradeceria :D

Esto es lo que tengo en mi aplicacion de c#

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
    <label>Titulo de Lanzamiento</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tipoApp" name="tipoApp" data-init-plugin="select2" required>
       <option value=" "></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y esta es mi tabla

```
create table Portal
(
  Id_Dashboard int,
  Fecha_Activacion date,
  Fecha_Vencimiento date, 
  Pais varchar(200),
  Titulo_Lanzamiento varchar(200),
  Nombre_Banner varchar(200),
  Url_Img varchar(200),
  Estatus int
)
```

Los titulos que busco obtener son de acuerdo al pais

Comment: Tu pregunta no es para nada clara. Un select donde? como es tu tabla? donde quieres mostrarlo? Has intentado algo? Si es asi, puedes ponernos algo de código para que podamos ayudarte? Pásate por [ask]

Comment: muestra el código que has usado y así  sera mas fácil ayudarte, pueda que tal vez has omitido algo

Comment: @LuisAcuña ya lo he editado. Y Luis lo que me dices no lo tengo es que la informacion que he encontrado ha sido en PHP y me he perdido al tratar de pasarla para c#

Answer (score 1):

Bueno tienes que crear la conexion a tu base de datos y le asignas al datasource de tu lista el resultado de tu consulta:

```
string ConnectString = "server=**tu servidor**;database=**nombre de tu base de datos**;integrated security=SSPI"; //reemplazala por tu cadena de conexion
string QueryString = "select * from Portal";

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectString);   
command = new SqlCommand("SELECT_LANZAMIENTO", myConnection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

connection.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

tipoApp.DataSource = dt;
tipoApp.DataTextField = "Pais";
tipoApp.DataValueField = "Id_Dashboard";
tipoApp.DataBind();
```

Comment: Cree este procedimiento almacenado, que es lo mismo que la consulta:
`CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_LANZAMIENTO
  @P_PAIS VARCHAR(200),
  @P_TIT_LANZ VARCHAR(200)
AS
select NUMB_ID_DASHBOARD AS ID_DASH,
    PAIS AS PAIS,
    TITULO_LANZAMIENTO AS TIT_LANZ
FROM LANDINGPAGE.PORTAL
where NUMB_ESTATUS = 1 AND PAIS = @P_PAIS`

Creo que omiti algo importante, lo estoy desarrollando bajo MVC y esto lo tengo en un modelo

Comment: ya actualice el codigo

Comment: ya lo estoy checando, es sólo que no se me ocurre como esto lo puedo poner para mandar llamar en el `<select>`.Perdón es que no habia trabajado antes con MVC y se muy poco en c#

Comment: ohh es mvc, disculpa no habia leido esto antes

Comment: No te preocupes, deja sigo pensando como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tienes esa sola tabla y que pasas país como parámetro. Lo primero que tienes que hacer es guardar en una colección todos los Portal cuyo país sea igual al recogido como parm.
tu controlador:

```
public ActionResult Prueba(string pais )
{           
    var collection = db.Portals.Where(s => s.Pais == pais).ToList();
    ViewBag.Titulos = new SelectList(collection, "Titulo_Lanzamiento", "Titulo_Lanzamiento")
    return View();
}
```

y en formulario utiliza el helper html para renderizar el ViewBag como lo que quieres

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Titulos", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control")
```

Nota: para este ejemplo utilizo Entity Framework y LINQ pero la idea es esa, espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Gracias, lo intentare :D

Comment: tambien cuando digo db.  me refiero a que tengo definido un Contexto, pues me basé en una aplicación que tenia en la que utilizo Code First. No se si estarás familiarizado con este tipo de práctica